# How to limit array size in supabase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database-design, supabase

I am making an application which involves users storing their favorite content series (which each have a unique ID).

The problem is  : I want to check if those IDs exists in the database and also to limit the size of this list to a floor (~100 items).

So far, I have tried to implement a RLS policy but checking the content of the posted data is too complex especially for arrays.

I am considering the use of a sort of gateway API that makes a bridge between the user and the database of their profile to insure more checks but before working on that I want to be sure there is no way to implement this by relying on Supabase only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a database constraint to limit the size of the list to a floor of 100 items. Additionally, you can use a SQL query to check if the IDs exist in the database.

To limit the size of the list, you can use a check constraint on the table that stores the user's favorite content series. The check constraint can be defined to ensure that the size of the array is not greater than 100.

To check if the IDs exist in the database, you can use a SQL query with the "IN" operator. The query can be written to check if each ID in the user's list exists in the database.

These solutions can be implemented using Supabase only, without the need for a gateway API.